# Create BigQuery table schema corresponding to table in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, google-bigquery, jooq

We are trying to copy an Oracle DB (v19c) to BigQuery and wondering what is the best way to create BigQuery table [schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas). We can't hardcode the schema because the code will need to copy arbitrary table so we don't know at compile time what the schema of the source table is going to be. We are using jOOQ, does it have a helper method that given a table, returns Schema for BQ?

```
com.google.cloud.bigquery.Schema getBQSchema(String oracleTableName)
```

If not, how to best go about it?

Comment: Why would you want to? BigQuery is not optimised the same way as Oracle. The design patterns are different and so you should be transforming the data as it is replicated. I strongly recommend against copying a fully normalised / transactional schema into BigQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jOOQ, the type you're looking for is [`org.jooq.Meta`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Meta.html). It allows you to query your database meta data, based on JDBC's [`DatabaseMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.sql/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html), by default (which you can also use directly, of course).

Any [`org.jooq.Table`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Table.html) that comes out of this `org.jooq.Meta` type should have a reference to the [`org.jooq.Schema`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Schema.html) that it's defined in. It's not of the type `com.google.cloud.bigquery.Schema`, but you can probably populate your own lookups based on the above?

Comment: Thanks. JDBC DatabaseMetaData is the way to go